# How can i get all dags details from airflow rest api

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-api, airflow-taskflow

i have more dags (say 150dags) in my airflow account.
My airflow version = 2.4.0

im using url and query parameter
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/dags?limit=1000&offset=0

But my response consists only 100 records(dags).
i think query parameters are not working here.

How can i fetch all dags available inside my airflow.

Comment: are all dags active ? cause by default only_active=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/29773/files) that explain that the limit can not be passed and if you put more then the limit the fallback would be the limit

if you want to change the limit in the api, you can change "maximum_page_limit" in airflow.cfg to other number (default = 100)

Another option is to play with offset until you do not get dags in the list. for example : first call limit=100, offset=0, second call limit=100, offset=101 and so on until empty response.

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/dags?limit=100&offset=0
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/dags?limit=100&offset=101
```

also, an option not in the api is to create a dag with a task and using DagBag to get all dags details.

in this example I print all the dag ids

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG, settings
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import DagBag

with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args={
            "start_date": datetime(2022, 1, 1),
            "retries": 0,
            "catchup": False,
        },
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["test"],
) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = __doc__


    @task
    def print_dags():
        dagbag = DagBag(settings.DAGS_FOLDER)
        print(dagbag.dags.keys())


    (print_dags())
```

Comment: ok, But if im already having multiple dags , how can i able to get all dags through rest api.

Comment: @vbalavbala, what is the total_entries you see in the json ? also are all active? by default only_active=True

Comment: in response json, i  have 100 dags details under "dags" key and under "total_entries" key i have value 110, 
Also in my account i have 110 dags.
all dags are active dags.

Comment: update my answer, there is parameter "maximum_page_limit" in airflow.cfg that can be changed

Comment: OK , Other than this , is there any other way for this approach?

Comment: I think there is, play with the offset by making few calls. updated my answer

Comment: suppose if im having 150 dags , how can i make use of offset &limit query parameter.
give some example for this.

Comment: @vbalavbala I updated my answer with an example of to api calls.of course you can write a loop until no items in the response

Answer (score 0):

My approach of this issue [python](/questions/tagged/python), [requests](/questions/tagged/requests),[airflow](/questions/tagged/airflow),[python3](/questions/tagged/python3),[aws](/questions/tagged/aws),[awslambda](/questions/tagged/awslambda)[api](/questions/tagged/api)

```py
import json
import requests

url = f"https://airflow.com/api/v1/dags"

headers = {
    'Authorization': "Basic <your_authentication_token>",  # Replace with your actual token
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

try:
    # Set the limit for records to retrieve per iteration (Not required but useful for next step)
    limit_per_itr = 100
    airflow_url = f"{url}?only_active=true&limit={limit_per_itr}"
    
    # Make the initial GET request to retrieve DAGs
    response = requests.get(airflow_url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    # Create a list to store all DAGs
    All_Dag_List = []
    
    # Retrieve the JSON data from the response
    all_dag_data = response.json()
    
    # Get the total number of entries
    total_entries = all_dag_data['total_entries']
    
    # Add the initial set of DAGs to the list
    All_Dag_List.extend(all_dag_data['dags'])
    
    # Calculate the number of iterations required to fetch all DAGs
    number_of_itr = (total_entries // limit_per_itr)
    
    # Loop through additional iterations to fetch remaining DAGs
    for next_itr in range(number_of_itr):
        num_of_record = len(All_Dag_List)
        new_airflow_url = f"{airflow_url}&offset={num_of_record}"
        
        # Make a GET request for the next set of DAGs
        response = requests.get(new_airflow_url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        
        # Retrieve JSON data for the next set of DAGs
        all_dag_data = response.json()
        
        # Extract and store DAG IDs from the response
        temp_list_of_dag_id = [item['dag_id'] for item in all_dag_data['dags']]
        All_Dag_List.extend(all_dag_data['dags'])
        
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # Handle errors related to the request
    print(f'Error connecting to Airflow: \n{str(e)}')
    All_Dag_List = None
    
except Exception as e:
    # Handle other exceptions
    print(f'An error occurred: {str(e)}')
    All_Dag_List = None

# At this point, All_Dag_List contains all the retrieved DAGs or is None in case of an error.
```